# Firefox loses web connection after a while

Tags: firefox

I have a misbehaving installation of Firefox that looses it's connection to the web after 15 - 30 mins of being open. The machine remains connected and other browsers continue to work flawlessly.

Current work around is to close and re-open Firefox.

Doing this normally results in one of the following happening:

- Getting an error message that Firefox is still open
- Firefox crashes on close

Has anyone seen this before or have any idea how to fix?

I've tried a reinstall that preserves user settings (rename the "Mozilla Firefox" folder to "OldFirefox" and run the installer).

Edit:

I'm using Windows 7 with Firefox 43.0.4.

Crash report: https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/507977ff-f847-4780-8778-5a37e2160107

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on. Please [edit] your question and add your Operating System and the version of Firefox you are running. It would also be helpful to see your crash reports: about:crashes will give a link you can include in your question.

Comment: updated question to include this information :)

Comment: Have you tried running with a new profile and/or running with add-ons disabled?

Comment: 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: I belive it's the 32 bit version. I haven't tried running under a new profile

Comment: Try with a new profile next. Also try with add-ons disabled.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour on other browsers? IE or Chrome perhaps? That way we can ascertain whether it's a system-level issue or Firefox being Firefox.